# Cohomology of Line Bundle of Blow-up of $\mathbb{A}^2$ at origin

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be the blow-up of $\mathbb{A}^2$ at the origin and let $p_2: X \to \mathbb{P}^1$ be the induced map and $L_n = p_2^\ast(\mathcal{O}(n))$. How can I compute the higher direct images $R^i\pi_\ast(L_n)$, where $\pi: X\to \mathbb{A}^2$ is the blow up map, for each $n\in \mathbb{Z}$?

Here is my progress: I know that $p_2^\ast: Pic(\mathbb{P}^1) \to Pic(X)$ is an isomorphism, so $L_n$ can be thought of as either $\mathcal{O}(n)$ or $\mathcal{O}(-n)$ via restriction. By Grothendieck vanishing, $R^i\pi_\ast(L_n) = 0$ for $i\geq 3$. In fact $R^2\pi_\ast(L_n) = 0$ by Proposition 8.5 in Hartshorne which states in this case that $R^i\pi_\ast(L_n) = \widetilde{H^i(Y, L_n)}$. We then find an affine cover consisting of two sets both isomorphic to $\mathbb{A}^2$ and appealing to Cech cohomology and observing that there are no intersections beyond $i= 1$, so $H^i = 0$ for $i\geq 2$ to see $R^2\pi_\ast(L_n)$ is also zero.

Is there a nice way to proceed further? I am aware that I can also think of $X$ as the total space of the tautological bundle on $\mathbb{P}^1$, so perhaps there is a way to intuit what is going on topologically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First,
$$
H^0(\mathbb{A}^2,R^i\pi_*L_n) = H^i(X,L_n)
$$
by the standard spectral sequence since $\mathbb{A}^2$ is affine hence quasi-cohenrent sheaves do not have higher cohomology on it. Second,
$$
H^i(X,L_n) = H^i(\mathbb{P}^1, R^0p_*L_n)
$$
by the same spectral sequence since $p = p_2$ is an affine map hence higher derived functors of $p_*$ vanish. Finally,
$$
p_*L_n = p_*p^*\mathcal{O}(n) \cong \mathcal{O}(n) \otimes p_*\mathcal{O}_X = \mathcal{O}(n) \otimes \Big(\bigoplus_{i=0}^\infty \mathcal{O}(i) \Big) = \bigoplus_{i=0}^\infty \mathcal{O}(i+n).
$$
Combining all this we obtain
$$
H^0(\mathbb{A}^2,R^1\pi_*L_n) = \bigoplus_{i=0}^\infty H^1(\mathbb{P}^1, \mathcal{O}(i+n)).
$$
Note that this is an isomorphism of modules over the ring of functions on $\mathbb{A}^2$, hence it also determines the coherent sheaf $R^1\pi_*L_n$.

Comment: Ah that is really helpful, thanks a lot!